# character level exchang in USB smart card class specification

Tags: usb, character, specifications

in USB: smart card class standard there are 3 level exchange including 1:APDU level 2: TPDU level 3: character level. what's difference between these levels? Also, what's mean exactly `character level`?

sorry for my bad english writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is less formal control defined in the specification as one proceeds up the levels from TPDU through APDU to level 3 character level exchanges.

From the spec, [3.2.3](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/DWG_Smart-Card_CCID_Rev110.pdf):

> Character level of exchanges is selected when none of the TPDU, Short APDU or Short and extended APDU is selected.
>   The CCID sends the characters in the command (maybe none) then waits for the number of characters (if not null) indicated in the command.
>   For character level exchange between the host and the CCID, the CCID supports asynchronous characters communication with the ICC as per ISO 7816-3 § 6.3 including
>   Page 14 of 123 CCID Rev 1.1
>   DWG Smart-Card Integrated Circuit(s) Card Interface Devices
>   timings defined in ISO/IEC 7816-3 § 8.2 for T = 0 and in ISO 7816-3 § 9.3 for T = 1. To respect timing the CCID shall use the defined parameters.
>   The CCID implements the character frame and character repetition procedure when T = 0 is selected.

This is all part of defining the nature of exchange:

> 3.2 Protocolandparametersselection
>   A CCID announces in dwFeatures Table 5.1-1 one level of exchanges with the host, TPDU, APDU (Short and Extended), or Character.

TPDU is the first of the exchanges specified, and APDU is the second.

> 3.2.1 TPDU level of exchange
>   For TPDU level exchanges, the CCID provides the transportation of host’s TPDU to the ICC’s TPDU. The TPDU format changes according to the protocol or for PPS exchange.
>   TPDU for PPS exchange has the following format:
>   Command TPDU:
>   FF PPS0 PPS1 PPS2 PPS3 PCK, with PPS1, PPS2, PPS3 optional [ISO/IEC7816-3 §7].
>   Response TPDU:
>   FF PPS0_R PPS1_R PPS2_R PPS3_R PCK_R, with PPS1_R, PPS2_R, PPS3_R optional [ISO/IEC7816-3 §7.4).
>   The CCID implements and verifies timings and protocol according to its parameters settings to assume ISO/IEC 7816-3 §7.1, §7.2. No check on frame format is mandatory on request, and on response the only recommended analysis is the most significant nibble of PPS0_R to compute the number of bytes left to receive.
>   A CCID that implements automatic PPS should not accept TPDU for PPS exchange and must check for PPS response validity.
>   T = 0 TPDU can have three formats [ISO/IEC 7816-3, § 8.3.2]:
>   - Form 1, no data to exchange with ICC, only header:
>   Command TPDU = CLA INS P1 P2, the CCID is responsible to add P3=00h. Response TPDU = SW1 SW2
>   - Form 2, data expected from ICC:
>   Command TPDU = CLA INS P1 P2 Le, Le=P3 from 00h to FFh (00h means 100h)
>   Response TPDU = Data(Le) SW1 SW2, Data(Le) is for the Le data received from the ICC or empty if ICC rejects the command.
>   - Form 3, data are to be sent to the ICC:
>   Command TPDU = CLA INS P1 P2 Lc Data(Lc), Lc=P3 from 01h to FFh and Data(Lc) for the Lc data to send to the ICC.
>   Response TPDU = SW1 SW2
>   The CCID, for T=0 TPDU, is in charge of managing procedure bytes (ISO 7816-3 § 8.3.3) and character level [ISO]IEC 7816-3 § 8.2].
>   The procedure bytes are not mapped into the response TPDU except for the SW1 SW2 bytes. The CCID implements and verifies timings according to its
>   ￼CCID Rev 1.1 Page 13 of 123
>   DWG Smart-Card Integrated Circuit(s) Card Interface Devices
>   ￼parameters settings to assume ISO/IEC 7816-3 § 8.2 (work waiting time, extra guard time, ...). If ICC uses NULL procedure byte (60h) the CCID informs the host of this request for time extension.
>   T = 1 TPDU command and response use the frame format [ISO/IEC 7816-3 § 9.4]. The CCID expects the respect of the character frame [ISO/IEC 7816-3 § 9.4.1]. But no check on frame format is mandatory on sending, and on receiving. The only recommended checks are:
>   - Expecting LEN byte as third byte
>   - Wait for LEN bytes as INF field.
>   - Wait for an EDC field which length complies with parameter bmTCCKST1 (see § 6.1.7).
>   The CCID implements and verifies timing according to its parameters settings to assume ISO/IEC 7816-3 § 9.5.3 (CWT, BWT, BGT, ...).
>   The detection of parity error on character received is optional. The interpretation of first bytes received as NAD and PCB to manage VPP is optional and depends on CCID capabilities.
>
> 3.2.2 APDU level of exchange
>   For APDU level exchanges, the CCID provides the transportation of host’s APDU to ICC’s TPDU.
>   APDU commands and responses are defined in ISO 7816-4.
>   Two APDU levels are defined, short APDU and extended APDU. Short APDU and extended APDU are defined in ISO/IEC 7816-4 § 5.3.2.
>   A CCID that indicates a short APDU exchange only accepts short APDU. A CCID that indicates an extended APDU exchange accepts both short APDU and extended APDU.
>   If the ICC requests time extension, by using a NULL procedure byte (60h) in T=0 protocol or S(WTX) in T=1 protocol, the CCID informs the host of this request.
>   A CCID supporting APDU level of exchanges implements a high level of automatism in ICC communications. It shall also provide a high level of automatism in ATR treatment and implement one of the following automatisms: automatic parameters negotiation (proprietary algorithm), or automatic PPS according to the current parameters. At least two standards of transportation for APDU are defined, ISO/IEC 7816-4 and EMV 3.1.1, which standard to implement is out of the scope of this specification.

Comment: the main part of my question is the difference between these levels? i cannot see any difference between some examples of different levels in this spec.